# Почему auto-fit и auto-fill не переносят блоки?

Tags: css3, css-grid

Код `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));` должен переносить грид элементы на новую строку когда они перестают влазить в блок при заданной минимальной ширине, но они этого не делают, даже при ширине экрана 320px и минимальной ширине блока 300px элементы не переносятся, отладчик почему то говорит что они шириной более 300px хотя очевидно что это не так, если открыть с телефона блоки тоже не переносятся, в чём дело?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[ссылка на пример с гридами](https://www.quackit.com/html/html_editors/scratchpad/preview.cfm?example=/css/grid/tutorial/create_a_responsive_grid_auto-fill_vs_auto-fit)